# Developing .NET Web Service from WSDL file

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

What's the best practices for developing a web service with a WSDL as a start point?

Comment: Are you trying to reverse-engineer the WSDL from an existing service (possibly non-.NET) and create a new .NET web service with equivalent WSDL?

Comment: Do you mean a WCF service, or a legacy ASMX service?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vaque, but developing web services with .net is quite easy.

Using visual studio, most of the things are generated for you. You can add methods as

```
[WebMethod]
public string hello(){
    return "hello"
}
```

and luckily once you deploy it, the wsdl is generated for you.

If you are looking to download some entities from a wsdl, you can use the wsdl utility and invoke a wsdl to download the entity class.

Answer (score 1):

Use SvcUtil to generate your service interface and then develop a service against that. [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/09/24/wsdl-first-development-with-wcf.aspx) is an example.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [WCF Developer Center on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/WCF) - it has tons of tutorials, article, screencasts that show you how to create a SOAP based web service, based on code or WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question helpful when I had the same question in the past.

[Create an ASMX web service from a WSDL file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548314/create-an-asp-net-web-service-from-a-wsdl-file)

The problem I had was that I was given a WSDL. I needed to create web service methods based on the contract that the WSDL provided.