# using a wsdl in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wsdl

I have downloaded a WSDL file from Internet and just want to know how to use the webservices out of the provided wsdl file using ASP.net version 2.0.

Comment: [Create an ASMX web service from a WSDL file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548314/create-an-asmx-web-service-from-a-wsdl-file)
All you need to do is create a class that inherits from the interface that WSDL.EXE has generated, and then implement the methods from the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is answered [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548314/create-an-asmx-web-service-from-a-wsdl-file): You can use WSDL.exe to generate a client, which you can access from code.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add a web service reference. Back in Visual Studio 2005, this was in the context menu of the project and is called "Add Web Reference". In the dialog, just enter the location where you downloaded the WSDL file and a proxy will be generated for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
When you use Add Service reference
```

The “Address” text box at the top can be used to type the URL to the Service Description, or `“WSDL” file`. Since the service is in the same solution as the project we’re trying to add it to, we can take advantage of the “Discover” dropdown at the right. Clicking the arrow shows “Services in this solution”:

Follow these links for detailed information:

[How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/)

[How to use WSDL file](http://forums.asp.net/t/989366.aspx) - asp.net forum thread